# Reference to undeclared entity 'middot'

Tags: c#, rest, github-api

I am working with GitHub REST API in C#. The code was working fine, and after some days, today, I got this error. Any idea where shall I start?

```
Exception caught: System.ApplicationException: Error retrieving response.  Check
 inner details for more info. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Reference to undeclared entity 'middot'. Line 7, position 28.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleGeneralEntityReference(String name, Boolean isInAttributeValue, Boolean pushFakeEntityIfNullResolver, Int32 entityStartLinePos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishPartialValue()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.get_Value()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
   at RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer.Deserialize[T](IRestResponse response)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.Deserialize[T](IRestRequest request, IRestResponse raw)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DevOps.RestSharpAPI.Execute[T](RestClient client, RestRequest request) in
C:\2015\C#\DevOps\RESTLibrary\RestSharpAPI.cs:line 75
   at DevOps.GitHubAPI.GetGitHubUser() in C:\2015\C#\DevOps\GitHub\GitHubAPI.cs:line 44
   at DevOps.GitHubAPI.Main(String[] args) in C:\2015\C#\DevOps\GitHub\GitHubAPI.cs:line 169
```

Comment: Looks like there is a mismatch in the DTD (the set of entities) expected by your API client vs. sent by GitHub.

Comment: @Slaks, I am using the latest RestSharp 105.2.3, and our GitHub instance remains the same version. Don't know how this could happen. Do you know how to fix this? 'middot' sounds like the "." in the middle of something.

Comment: @Slaks, sorry, my URL got changed to something wrong.

Comment: No; `&middot;` is a standard HTML (but not XML) entity.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you guys know, I accidentally changed this:

```
static string baseUrl = "http://github.mycompany.com/api/v3";
```

to

```
static string baseUrl = "http://github.com/api/v3";
```

Once I change it back, the error is gone. Hard to figure out.